# Text File Reading and Parsing

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, streamreader

First of all, I'm VERY new to using C# (or any programming language for that matter).

I am trying to create a GUI for pulling up machine programs for operators. I want the interface:
1) to have a part # combo box drop-down from a list of directories (this part is done)
2) based on the part #, I want to populate a second combo-box with Operation names from a text file contained in that part's directory. The file has a specific format as follows:

OPERATION REV B

C_3000-B_2.7MM_LOCK_COMP_PLATE_PED_GAGE_GPN-00023C.PRG

OPERATION REV A

C_3000-A_2.7MM_LOCK_COMP_PLATE_PED_GAGE_GPN-00023B.PRG

I want whatever follows "OPERATION" to appear in the second combo box drop down. Once the selections are made from the combo-boxes, I want the programs listed under the OPERATION line to be copied to a "working folder" and executed by another software. I have done a lot of reading and searching and video watching, but I just can't quite get there.

I'm hung up on getting the value of the string after OPERATION to appear in the second combobox right now much less the copying of files.

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    public string OpsPath = "D:\\CMM\\ProgramOps\\";
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DirectoryInfo obj = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\CMM\\ProgramOps\\");
        DirectoryInfo[] folders = obj.GetDirectories();
        cmboxParts.DataSource = folders;

    }

    private void cmboxParts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cmboxOps.Items.Clear();
        cmboxOps.SelectedItem = null;
        string Part = (cmboxParts.SelectedItem as string);
        string Opfile = ("D:\\CMM\\ProgramOps\\" + Part +".OP");

        try
        {
            string line;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Opfile);
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) !=null)
            {
                if line.StartsWith("OPERATION")
                string[] Ops = line.Split(' ');
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I realize this is a big project for a newbie, but I guess one has to start somewhere.

I read a little about using Regex, but it was a little over my head.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. After `if line.StartsWith("OPERATION")` you are create a string array, what are you doing with that array?

Comment: If this is the format of the file, I personally would create a class object that holds the Operation and Program. Read through the entire file creating a new objects to hold these values and store them in the combobox. Then from there you can get the Program from the selection in the combobox to pass on. But as it stands right now, you have the line split and should be able to fill the combobox with a concatenation of `Ops[1] + " " + Ops[2]`

Comment: @AndrewE I posted what I have so far in the code. I was going to try an parse the lines and add the array items to the combobox. As I said, I am very new to programming, so this is pretty difficult for me.